# Concatenate 2 vars simultaniously

Tags: php

Simplified the problem.

$var1 should be "1245"

$var2 should be "1345"

The aim is when assigning common values ("1","4","5") - need to assign only once.

```
$var1="";
$var2="";

$var1.="1"; //need same content for $var2
$var1.="2"; //this is for var1 only
$var2.="3"; //this is for var2 only
$var1.="4"; //need same content for $var2
$var1.="5"; //need same content for $var2
```

This is NOT what I am looking for:

```
$var1="";
$var2="";

$var1.="1";
$var1.="2";
$var1.="4";
$var1.="5";

$var2.="1";
$var2.="3";
$var2.="4";
$var2.="5";
```

Because I want the following assignments to appear only once in the code:

```
.="1";
.="4";
.="5";
```

I hope I am explicit.

EDIT:
tried this:

```
$var1=""; $var2="";
$var2.=$var1.="1";
$var1.="2";
$var2.="3";
$var2.=$var1.="4";
$var2.=$var1.="5";

//$var1=>1245
//$var2=>131241245


$var1=""; $var2="";
$var1.=$var2.="1";
$var1.="2";
$var2.="3";
$var1.=$var2.="4";
$var1.=$var2.="5";

//$var1=>121341345
//$var2=>1345
```

Comment: Do you want to add what you've already tried?

Comment: Why would you need to do this? What are you really trying to do?

Comment: blender: i want to avoid duplicating content strings in code

Comment: I don't really understand what are you trying to do. `$var1 should be "1245 and $var2 should be 1345` -- so, use `$var1 = 1245; $var2 = 1345;` -- what's wrong with that?

Comment: Amal Murali: the problem is simplified.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Starting from the other answers, I came up with a solution that is more comfortable for me:

```
$var1[]=$var2[]="1";
$var1[]="2";
$var2[]="3";
$var1[]=$var2[]="4";
$var1[]=$var2[]="5";
$var1=implode("",$var1);
$var2=implode("",$var2);

//$var1=1245
//$var2=1345
```

Comment: My edit in this post makes four separate people (including a moderator) who have edited out the chatty material. References about (not) adding religious proselytism are available on _Meta_ if you need them.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$var1 = $var2 = "1245";
$var2[1] = "3";
```

Or:

```
$var1 = $var2 = '1';
$var1 = $var2 .= '2';
$var1 = $var2 .= '4';
$var1 = $var2 .= '5';
$var2[1] = '3';
```

Comment: Have you tested? Your first snippet will give you $var1: 121341345;
$var2: 1345; The 2nd snippet is not concatenating 2 variables simultaneously, which is what OP is trying to do.

Comment: @shreddeR: did YOU test it? Both snippets work perfectly. Remember that in PHP, the result of an assignment is the value being assigned... In the second snippet, $var2 is concatted with the new digit, and then the fully concatted string is assigned to $var1.

Comment: Marc B: the second snippet was edited and corrected, shredder was referring to previous version which was incorrect.

Comment: @MarcB His first snippet was edited out and not recorded. And so I removed my -1

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$var1 = $var2 = "5";
$var1 = $var2 = "4" . $var2;
$var2 = "3" . $var2;
$var1 = "2" . $var1;
$var2 = "1" . $var2;
$var1 = "1" . $var1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to split the two vars into array.

```
    $var1 = "1234";

    $var2 = "145";

    $tab1 = str_split($var1);
    $tab2 = str_split($var2);
    $tab3 = array();

    foreach($tab1 as $value){
     if(in_array($value, $tab2))
      {
        $tab3[] = $value;
      }

    }
return implode('', $tab3);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have limited number of variables that you want to modify, you can create a helper function that references passed variables:

```
function append($append, &$var1, &$var2 = null) {
    $var1 .= $append;
    if ($var2 !== null) {
        $var2 .= $append;
    }
}
```

And use it like

```
$var1 = $var2 = '';
append('1', $var1, $var2);
append('2', $var1);
append('3', $var2);
append('4', $var1, $var2);
append('5', $var1, $var2);

var_dump($var1,$var2);
```